# Euler Characteristic of smallest 1-dimensional simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose you have a simplicial complex with two 0-simplicies and a 1-simplex connecting them. What is the Euler Characteristic of this space? In ascii art:

x----x

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Basically I tried taking the vertices - edges to get 1. But https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic contains this image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#/media/File:Euler_characteristic_hypercube_simplex.svg which clearly labels it as 2.

Comment: You're right, it's 1. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Surfaces. I think that the first entry in the picture you referenced is supposed to be the 0-sphere, two vertices and no edges: it is clearly labeled as having no edges.

Comment: I guess I'm confused since the 0-sphere is just two points, and not path connected, but the picture clearly is path connected. So I guess I don't understand why there is a line drawn between the two points if there wanted to depict the 0-sphere.

Comment: You're not confused: the picture is wrong.